# How can I remove the extra bottom tab bar created in my tabs page

Tags: ios, swift, swrevealviewcontroller

I want to create a side bar menu using SWReveal framework and I try to add it in one of the bottom tabs pages but when I switch to that tab I have an extra space of bottom tab and I can't remove it can anyone help?

[image]

I mean this black tab above of home tab.

Comment: Can you share the code, how you implement the sidebar menu?

Comment: http://s8.picofile.com/file/8305654068/Screen_Shot_1396_06_14_at_23_56_52.png

Comment: i did this in storyboard @EmreÖnder

Comment: @DanaAmiri did you fix this issue, If you find out any solutions please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set tabBar Translucent

> self.tabBar.translucent = false

Comment: I can't hide bottom bar space as per your code, Can you please help me ?